# Install ggplot2 in jupyter notebook when using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook

I want to work in jupyter notebook using R codes.

Now I'd like to draw graphs but I can't install ggplot2. Every time I try to install ggplot2, error message pops up like below.

Could you let me know how to solve this problem? (I want to use R code in jupyter notebook like what I usually do in R).

```
installing the source packages 'lifecycle', 'scales', 'ggplot2'

Warning message in install.packages("ggplot2"):
"installation of package 'lifecycle' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("ggplot2"):
"installation of package 'scales' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("ggplot2"):
"installation of package 'ggplot2' had non-zero exit status"
```

---

[image]

Comment: Are you running a conda environment?

Comment: Conda environment means I downloaded Anaconda and installed R in Anaconda prompot entering the code, conda install -c r r-essentials? If so, yes

Comment: So it is recommended to install r packages from anaconda as well: `conda install ggplot2` or !conda install ggplot2 in the notebook

Comment: @RicVillalba Ideally, that is `%conda install ggplot2` you should be suggesting for running in a cell inside the notebook. The modern magic install commands were added to insure installation occurs in the environment backing the kernel underlying the notebook. See more about the modern magic install commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). Avoid the exclamation point for installs as it can lead to issues, see ...

Comment: <continued> the second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez). (Also I'm not sure that works in the irkernel? And so you'd use the magic install in typical Python kernel, I think.)